# pagination using WHERE and LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, pagination

What to do in the case when it is impossible to apply `"WHERE x < ..."` or `"WHERE x > ..."` because the column "x" has more identical values than the LIMIT value
For example.
There is a table "payments_list". It has columns "id", "description", "cost", "payment_deadline".
LIMIT = 3
Our sorting by "payment_deadline" ASC and "cost" ASC
Let's say we have a table:

| id | description | cost | payment_deadline | payment_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | descr... | 100 | 2023-10-01 | 2023-09-01 |
| 2 | descr... | 100 | 2023-10-01 | 2023-09-02 |
| 3 | descr... | 100 | 2023-10-01 | 2023-09-03 |
| 4 | descr... | 100 | 2023-10-13 | 2023-09-04 |
| 5 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-05 |
| 6 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-06 |
| 7 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-07 |
| 8 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-08 |
| 9 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-09 |
| 10 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-20 | 2023-09-10 |

When going to a page with a list of applications, the request:

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM payments_list
ORDER BY payment_deadline, cost
LIMIT 3;
```

When scrolling the page down, 3 more requests should be loaded, the request should already take into account the sorting and the last values ​​from the loaded table:

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM payments_list
WHERE payment_deadline > 2023-10-01 AND cost > 100
ORDER BY payment_deadline, cost
LIMIT 3;
```

The second request will also work correctly, but the next request will already skip some records

I understand that, as an option for the last entry, you can use something completely unique, for example, the date the application was created, or “id” (we have it ordered - bigint), but the user page is not always sorted by “id”

While I was writing this message, it seems that I gradually began to understand that in the expression `"WHERE ..."` you also need to specify a unique field (for example, "id"), and then for `"payment_deadline"` and `"cost"` specify ">=" instead of "> ". Then the expression of the second query will be `WHERE payment_deadline => 2023-10-01 AND cost => 100 AND id > 3`

The second query should return:

| id | description | cost | payment_deadline | payment_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | descr... | 100 | 2023-10-13 | 2023-09-04 |
| 5 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-05 |
| 6 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-06 |

The third query should return:

| id | description | cost | payment_deadline | payment_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-07 |
| 8 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-08 |
| 9 | descr... | 500 | 2023-10-18 | 2023-09-09 |

Tell me how to correctly compose a query in the case where there is multiple sorting

Comment: Look at `offset`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html#:~:text=OFFSET%20says%20to%20skip%20that%20many

Comment: I don't want to apply OFFSET, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make this work in the manner you originally show using just payment_deadline and cost, because there is no way to break joint ties in (payment_deadline,cost) in a consistent way.  You need to use a unique key to break ties.  Which apparently you already have in the "id" column.  So to get the next page, you would do:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM payments_list
WHERE (payment_deadline, cost, id) > ('2023-10-01',100,3)
ORDER BY payment_deadline, cost, id
LIMIT 3;
```

For the 2nd page the "id" column makes no apparent difference, as their is no tie at that breakpoint anyway.  But further down the list there are.

If you don't want to use the row comparator form, you could write it out the annoying way, but the way you originally did it is wrong.  You require the two column to both independently be greater than their cutoffs which isn't correct.  In the correct way the 1st one can be equal as long as the 2nd one is greater, and if the 1st is greater it doesn't matter what the 2nd is.

```
WHERE 
  payment_deadline > '2023-10-01' 
  or (payment_deadline = '2023-10-01' and cost > 100)
  or (payment_deadline = '2023-10-01' and cost = 100 and id>3)
```

This has the advantage that you can mix and match your ordering direction, but it won't allow efficient index support.

My general approach is not to do paging at all.  Let the client software download some generous but reasonable amount of data (say, up to 10,000 rows) ordered by their choice, and then let the client use its own memory and CPU to subdivide those into 3-row pages locally if it wants to.  Almost no one is going to want to look through more than 10,000 entries one page at a time anyway, except a screen scraper.  If you want to encourage screen scrapers, you should just include a button to download the entire dataset.  And if you don't want to encourage them, don't provide features which encourage them.

Comment: And what will the “WHERE” expression look like when the columns have different sorting directions, for example: `“payment_deadline” DESC and “cost” ASC`?

Comment: @dutik You would negate the numeric value and then sort the negation ASC.  If you have two non-numeric columns which need opposite sorting, there is no way to do that.  You'd best design the system so that that is not necessary.

Comment: I would like to allow the user to sort the data the way he wants, that’s why I have this question, of course, if I don’t use either sorting or filtering, then it would be enough for me to use “id”. Maybe you will have some small ideas on how to get out of the situation?

Comment: You *can* use arbitrary sorting, but not with the tuple comparator format.  Which means it will probably be annoying to write and slow to run.

Answer (score 0):

The solution usually is to add a unique key to the condition as a tie breaker. If the last page you read ended with the row that has `id = 4`, you fetch the next page with

```
SELECT id, payment_deadline, ...
FROM payments_list
WHERE (payment_deadline, id) > ('2023-10-13', 4)
LIMIT 3;
```

The last row you get will be the one with `id = 7`, so for the next page you continue with

```
SELECT id, payment_deadline, ...
FROM payments_list
WHERE (payment_deadline, id) > ('2023-10-18', 7)
LIMIT 3;
```

To make this fast, create a multi-column index on `(payment_deadline, id)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to know the specific database dialect you are working with

Some clauses will work into a db2 database, but not on oracle, or mysql, or even a Microsoft Access database.

That said, a generic approach that would work with most databases.

So, for pagination you would need to provide in each query two fields:

1. The date itself.
2. The id as a tie breaker.

The WHERE clause does accept compound statements.

So, you could place a clause like

`WHERE ( (payment_deadline = :provided_date AND id > :provided_id ) OR (payment_deadline > :provided_date) )  AND ... your other clauses here ...`

UPDATE: considering your sort order also needs the COST, you need three fields, actually:

first field: date ; if date is equal , cost is a tie breaker, if cost is equal, id is the tie breaker.

You should change the sort order to `payment_deadline ASC, cost ASC, id ASC`

And then you have (considering the parameters :payment_deadline, :cost and :id)

`WHERE (  ( (payment_deadline > :payment_deadline ) OR (payment_deadline = :payment_deadline AND COST > :cost) OR (payment_deadline = :payment_deadline AND COST = :cost AND ID > :id ) )`

Comment: I indicated in the attached tags that this is PostgreSQL

Comment: Sorry, totally new to publishing answers to stack overflow. I didn't see any tags mentioning the dialect.